# shopify webhook integrity check is failing nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, shopify

Following [this](https://gist.github.com/andjosh/5c4f0244914adfd312e4)

I was getting error - Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object

So I changed to

```
   var msg = JSON.stringify(req.rawBody);
   var digest = crypto.createHmac('sha256', APP_SHARED_SECRET)
                     .update(Buffer.from(msg,'utf8'))
                    .digest('base64');
```

The signature (hmac-sha256) generated is different then what I am receiving in the request header !

Any clue or pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use JSON.parse, instead of JSON.stringify,  to parse the message before performing any other actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with a similar issue, but you want to use

```
new Buffer(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a solution, this is what worked for me

```js
const rawBody = req.rawBody; // expressjs

// omitted
...

const digest = crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", process.env.SHOPIFY_WEBHOOK_SECRET)
    .update(data)
    .digest("base64");

return crypto.timingSafeEqual(
    Buffer.from(digest, "utf8"),
    Buffer.from(req.headers["http_x_shopify_hmac_sha256"], "utf8")
);
```

I was using Serverless function in Vercel, hence I used the external npm package [`raw-body`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-body) to get the correct raw body

```js
const rawBody = await getRawBody(req);
```

**Notes**

- The raw body is required for hmac comparison because the `req.body` is a parsed object and `JSON.stringify` messes up the original payload.
- Comparing the hmac with `crypto.timingSafeEqual`, this function prevents leaking time information to the extent.